# WPF ListView still reserving space when collapsed

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollviewer

I have a WPF ListView within a ScrollViewer.

I need to collapse the ListView and I am trying withthis code (pretty striaghtoforward):

```
this.myListView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Problem is the ListView seems to be reserving the space even when collapsed - it disappears but the ScrollViewer doesn't accordingly resize.

Anything I am missing?

Any Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their answers - I found out that a globally applied style was causing the problem! Solved now.

Comment: can you share that style?

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Answer (score 2):

Possible reason could be that ScrollViewer by default shows its vertical ScrollBar.
Try to set **ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility** to **auto**.
You can write something like this:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

I hope it helps.